# Latex refuses to number chapters

Tags: chapters

Simply,

my chapters are not numbered. This is true for both numbers in the TOC (all entries start with **0.**, like 0.4.12, 0.3.3, 0.2, no matter which chapter they are in), neither are things I used to see present, like **Chapter 7** before chapter title.

Has anybody got any idea what could cause this? I am using fancyhdr, but nothing suspicious.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Some more information is needed. What class are you using?

Comment: book. I even tried setting pagestyle to fancy for every page, no success.

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is definitely needed.

Comment: The description of your output is consistent with starting every chapter with `\chapter*{something}` if that is not what you did, show what you did do

Comment: Without a MWE this is just guesswork. Have you used `\frontmatter` without later using `\mainmatter`? Have you change the value of the `secnumdepth` counter?

Comment: It seem that you are using `\section{}` commands  without  using a `\chapter{}` before, in a document class like `book`, but without my crystal ball and without your MWE it is really hard to guess what are you doing.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: That was it. Unfortunately, I had to figure that out myself (while producting MWE). Please post the answer so I can accept it.

Comment: >  *I had to figure that out myself (while producting MWE)*. Yet another reason why we like MWEs!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For book-like classes, `\frontmatter` disables the chapter numbering (but still adds unstarred `\chapter`'s to the TOC). The numbering is then resumed with `\mainmatter`. (The reason for this is that chapters in the front matter, such as a foreword or preface, are typically unnumbered but should be listed in the table of contents.)

Example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foreword}

\chapter{Preface}

\chapter*{Dedication}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

In the above the "Foreword" and "Preface" chapters are unnumbered but are listed in the table of contents. The "Dedication" chapter and the table of contents (which implicitly uses `\chapter*`) are unnumbered and not included in the table of contents. The "Introduction" chapter is numbered (1) and included in the table of contents.